# Getting error while running PowerShell scripts for Tridion DB creation

Tags: web8.5, database, installation

I am getting below error on running PowerShell scripts for Tridion Content Manager Database creation:

[image]

I can see there is error on Line Number 147 in Content Manager Data Base PowerShell script, on which it is basically trying to create Editorial db.

```
Invoke-MsSqlScript (Join-Path -path $PSScriptDir -childpath '..\Scripts\MSSQL\Create\EDT_CREATE.sql') "Creating Content Manager editorial database" -AsAdministrator
```

Any Clue on this?

Note : For my MTS user i am creating strong password which has @ in it, because password policy does not let me keep it simple 'tridion'

Answer (score 2):

I made a mistake while Copying MSSQL folder from SDL Installation Media to my SDLDBInstall/Scripts Folder, I copied wrong mssql folder. I just copied mssql folder which has subfolders as well along with all powershells, then it worked.

Comment: Glad you resolved your issue. In that case, please accept your own answer so the question becomes "closed".